# What are the benefits of a combined date and time picker?

Tags: datetimepicker

I am wondering what are the benefits of using a combined date+time picker if user still needs to input them as 2 separate entities, e.g.:
[image: Material-ui Date+Time Picker]

Wouldn't a combined picker require more cognitive effort since user is now facing 2 questions at once instead of 1 at a time?

Moreover, in my opinion (not tested), having a combined picker seems to distract users from using the manual entry option via keyboard which could potentially be faster.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: That particular picker looks kind of horrible (kind of like having to input a number by picking each digit from a dropdown), but conceptually "select a point in time" is just asking for one piece of information.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve to be honest. If being able to enter things in faster means that it is more likely for the user to make an error, is it really 'better'?

Answer (score 1):

1. Keyboard entry and ability to copy & paste the whole value is a big plus.
2. If changing date&time starts data fetching or another slow operation, those can be changed in same dialog to not trigger data refresh.
3. One less click when user does not need to open another dialog for entering the second part.